# Spring boot logback not logging to file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am using the spring-boot-start-web dependency in my web mvc application and making use of logback. I have a logback-spring.xml file located in my static resources directory with the following config

```
<property name="MY_LOG_FILE" value="C:\mylog.log" />

<appender name="MY_APPENDER"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>${MY_LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${MY_LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
```

```
<logger name="com.mydomain.myapp" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="MY_APPENDER" />
</logger>
```

When I use the logger in my controllers it correctly logs to the console output, but the file is nowhere to be found. As far as what I can find online it looks like i'm setting it up correctly, but obviously I am not.

EDIT: It ended up being resolved by performing a Maven Update Project on the parent project, this project was part of a larger system of modules.

Comment: Change the logback configuration file so that <configuration debug="true"> to see if there are any problems and your configuration is OK. Also, are administrative permissions needed to write to C:\? Try to change the path to something different.

Comment: @vempo Thanks for the ideas. I tried changing the log file to write somewhere else that definitely shouldn't require permissions, and still no luck. setting debug="true" didn't seem to have any effect when starting the app. Hmmm

Comment: That may indicate that you're not running with this configuration file. Review https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration to make sure the correct file is loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the  logback-spring.xml in your resources directory,not static directory.

Build your project with maven,then Check if your target/classes directory has the logback-spring.xml

By default,If you put a logback.xml in the root of your classpath it will be picked up from there (or logback-spring.xml to take advantage of the templating features provided by Boot)

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: Sorry I totally messed up typing this question, I do have it in mys resources, not resources/static. I know it's being picked up because if I for example specify an appender that doesn't exist then it blows up

Comment: for some reason doing a maven update on her parent project made it start working. this answer ended up leading me to figure it out, so I will mark it as accepted. thanks.

Comment: That's okey.Sometimes you need to rebuild,restart,reimport....As you know,it's quick and easy!

Comment: save my life, doc seems not telling that logback-spring.xml must be taken into target..